# How to reposition of object in the same image in Python deep learning model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am developing a `DL` model in which I need to reposition of the image object to certain location within the same image itself. Example:

https://vectorstock.com/royalty-free-vector/lemon-soft-drink-advertising-lemonade-can-ads-vector-20584763

From this image I need to reposition sprite bottle to right hand side.

How can I do that?

I have experimented with the `keras` library using `ImageDataGenerator` class,
but here I am getting different generated image for same width_shift_range and height as well for every run of model.
link here:

https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

How to fixed this issue.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=40, width_shift_range=0.2,height_shift_range=0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ImageDataGenerator` is used for data augmentation - it synthesises new samples by applying random transformations to training data based on the supplied parameters.

If you want to apply some fixed transformations, you can use `apply_affine_transform()` from `tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image` ([doc ref](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/apply_affine_transform)):

[image]

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import apply_affine_transform

#Load image
img = np.array(Image.open('../img.jpg'))

#Apply fixed transformations
shifted = apply_affine_transform(img, theta=45, tx=200, ty=200,
                                 row_axis=0, col_axis=1, channel_axis=2)

#Plot
f, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(5, 4))
axs[0].imshow(img)
axs[0].set_title('original')

axs[1].imshow(shifted)
axs[1].set_title('rotated, shifted')
[ax.axis('off') for ax in axs]
```